# Multiple Inheritance Levels in EF Code Firs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to figure out how to handle inheritance for multiple types. I have an existing Code First / EF / MVC project which has live data in a production environment. The system uses a type called a "Document" upon which many functions can be performed, and there are many associated tables that can link to the DocumentID.

There is currently as more differentiated kind of document, a purchase order, which implements some more specific properties, such as a collection of "OrderLines" which reference a Product, a Quantity and a Unit Price. There are some other fields that are specific to the purchase order as well. In additional to being distinct from the base document type in having "OrderLines", the purchase order is a Supply Side document, and as such, it's third party is a "Vendor". There may be other supply side documents that also have a vendor as a third party in the future.

I am now ready to implement a new document type that will be Demand Side, meaning it will have a third party called a customer. It also has a collection of OrderLines.

My system is currently set up as TPH, so the table is called "Documents" and there is a discriminator column that says that the documents inside are Purchase orders.

How can I add the new type and use inheritance to implement the OrderLines collection and the CustomerID / Customer link? It seems that c# cannot do multiple inheritance, so the following would be out of the question:

> Document -> OrderLinesDocument -> PurchaseOrder
>
> Document -> OrderLinesDocument -> Invoice
>
> Document -> VendorDocument -> PurchaseOrder
>
> Document -> CustomerDocument -> Invoice

Where the middle class would implement the fields that might be common to many documents but not all documents?

Is there a way to accomplish this using interfaces, and still have EF figure out the tables properly?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: it should be `First` @JohnSaunders :))

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance could be tricky in many ways - so my advice is to go 'easy' with it.

But just doing a typical OO design here will produce usable tables, structure. Maybe something like this could work for you...

```
public class Document
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLinesDocument : Document
{
    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public interface IVendorDocument
{
    ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
public class VendorDocument : Document, IVendorDocument
{
    public ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomerDocument
{
    ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerDocument : Document
{
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : OrderLinesDocument, IVendorDocument
{
    public ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice : Document, ICustomerDocument
{
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

The simplest solution IMO is using TPH (just 'as is' pretty much).

But as I said, careful with it - and it might not work for what you have in mind - i.e. you'd need to experiment, make sure Db records look optimal.

**btw.** you can use it like this if you didn't know, forgot to post that...

```
var query1 = db.Documents.OfType<PurchaseOrder>().ToList();
var query2 = db.Documents.OfType<Invoice>().ToList();

var query3 = db.Documents.OfType<CustomerDocument>().ToList();
var query4 = db.Documents.OfType<VendorDocument>().ToList();
var query5 = db.Documents.OfType<OrderLinesDocument>().ToList();

var query6 = db.Documents.OfType<Document>().ToList();
```

(try that to see how it actually works)

Comment: Would this solution work with foreign key properties in the interfaces? Instead of a collection of vendors, it is public virtual Vendor Vendor {get; set;} and [ForeignKey("Vendor")] public int? VendorID {get; set;}. There are also some specific functions on the derived classes. Validations and such that are specific to each document type.

Comment: Ideally it should - interfaces are not 'invasive' in any sense here - the 'classes' are (classes influence how tables are created) - interfaces only serve you to be able to access things accordingly. So you can put in interfaces all you want, but problem are the classes that implement that. I cannot tell you that, as each case is different, you can always break it. This is a test layout. Work out the details and when you get in trouble then think how to avoid it. There are no general rules - but to watch for 'cyclical' paths, logical relationships etc.

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to implement this yet. Sorry! I will report back once this is done.

Comment: Another question though - how would I access the differentiated types in a view? Meaning If I am looping through a list of a type that references a document, and then displaying properties of that document, how does the view know which subtype it is? As far as the view knows, each one is a generic document. Should I be casting these inside of the view? Sounds wrong but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: the `Type` is telling you which doc it is. You can use `is ...` or even implement an `enum DocType` inside Document - and override for each doc type - then test against that - you can then 'switch' with that. You have all the info you need.

Comment: How do I decide what should go in an interface and what should go in a subtype?

Comment: Hmm. EF seems to add additional columns and FKs for each type that implements the interfaces. I am looking for a way to set up the inheritance so that by applying the interface, the new type uses the fields that are already on the table to link to the relational data. So if two types implement the collections they would utilize the same FK column in order to do so. With the solution outlined above, EF creates an new instance of the necessary column and appends a number to it, 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: I need your help! Can't get EF to use the same cols when implementing relationships through interfaces as above.

Comment: Hi @YHaber - quite busy, I don't have much time to devote to one answer - and I need to see that you're appreciating my effort. Anyhow - If you put in the base class - if navigation is shared - that doesn't create extra columns. If you have two (seemingly the same) nav properties in two derived - they would make different columns. I.e. what's 'the same' put into some base class again - then it won't be duplicated.

Comment: thanks for responding @NSGaga. the issue is that I need some of the derived types to have the navigation properties, and some not to. If I put them all in the base type then all will have the properties. I'm trying to get it where some of my documents can have a link to a vendor, but if they do have the link to vendor, they use the VendorID field to link. The same goes for all of the other navigational or special properties.

Comment: you'll just have to make more 'layers' and more base classes - e.g. I'm not talking about 'only one' base document - but - DocWithVendorsProperty - and others derive from it. I.e. (I didn't check but know from before) - if you 'share' the property via some base class - it doesn't get duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks, @NSGaga Do you think I should switch to TPT? Would it help at all? because I want to assign sets of properties to derived types, but since you can only derive from one base type, I would end up with CustomerDocumentThatHasPortsProductsandCancelDates, and even with that I would have to define the fields for ports and customers in a few base types anyways.